# Python3 translating to TI Basic Store function in for loop being weird (Fibonacci's sequence)

Tags: python-3.x, fibonacci, ti-basic

I just converted the Fibonacci's sequence from python3 to TI Basic but its acting kind of weird when I try to execute the function similar to "+=" operator to the iterator variable in python where I use the store function.
Here is my TI code below:

```
Input "Enter number of terms: ",N
0→A
1→B
0→I
If N≤0:Then
Disp "Please enter a positive integer"
End
If N=1:Then
Disp "Fibonacci sequence upto",N
Else:
Disp "Fibonacci sequence:"
For(I,0,N-1)
Disp A
A+B→C
B→A
C→B
I+1→I
End
End
```

where when I input 3, it gives me an output of:

```
0
1
```

rather than

```
0
1
1
```

The code works if I either remove or change this line:

```
I+1→I
```

to

```
I→I
```

Is there a reason why this causes the for loop to ignore one iteration instead of starting from this iteration?
Here is the corresponding python code:

```
#Fibonacci Sequence

N = int(input("Enter number of terms: "))
A= 0
B = 1
I = 0

if N <= 0:
  print("Please enter a positive integer")
if N == 1:
  print("Fibonacci sequence upto",N)
else:
  print("Fibonacci sequence:")
  for I in range(N):
      print(A)
      C = A + B
      A = B
      B = C
      I += 1
```

(I know that the I += 1 is unnecessary but it just made me curious why it doesn't work in the TIBasic language)

Original python fibonacci sequence code:
https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/examples/fibonacci-sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The for loop in ti basic iterates i by doing i = i+1.

The for loop in python sets i to a value from a sequence generated by range.

in other words
the ti code is more similar to

```html
for(let i=0; i<n; i++){
  
}
```

and the python script is more similar to

```html
let n = [1,2,4,5, ... n]

for(let ni=0; ni<n.length; ni++){
  let i=n[ni];
}
```

You can see how in the python example above, 'i' gets reset to a value from a list each iteration. where as in the ti example 'i' is used to keep track of the iteration state.